# How to refactor this code for a user inputed calculator application built in React?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, refactoring, calculator

Below is my code so far (and here's the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kirch-i1y58?file=/src/App.js:253-1766).

My specific refactoring question is how do I not duplicate the equation `Math.pow(0.01 * variableTwo * (460 + 26 * variableOne), 1.5` in both the clickHandler and the output box. The function of the click handler is to take whatever value is in the output field and use it as the new variable (Output One Variable) for the second equation. But I'm not sure how to do that so I just defaulted to using the equation again during the click handle.

```
export default function App() {


  const [variableOne, setVariableOne] = useState(0);
  const [variableTwo, setVariableTwo] = useState(0);
  const [outputOneVariable, setOutputOneVariable] = useState(0);
  const [link, setLink] = useState(false);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setOutputOneVariable(
      Math.pow(0.01 * variableTwo * (460 + 26 * variableOne), 1.5)
    );
    setLink(!link);
  };

  return (
    <div className="calculator-page">
      <h1>My Calculator</h1>
      <h3>Calculation One</h3>
      <div className="calculator-one">
        <UserInput
          label="Variable One"
          value={variableOne}
          onChange={(e) => setVariableOne(e.target.value)}
        />
        <UserInput
          label="Variable Two"
          value={variableTwo}
          onChange={(e) => setVariableTwo(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Output
          title="Output One"
          value={Math.pow(0.01 * variableTwo * (460 + 26 * variableOne), 1.5)}
        />
      </div>

      {link ? (
        <LinkOn onClick={clickHandler} />
      ) : (
        <LinkOff onClick={clickHandler} />
      )}

      <h3>Calculation Two</h3>

      <div className="calculator-two">
        <UserInput
          label="Output One Variable"
          value={outputOneVariable}
          onChange={(e) => setOutputOneVariable(e.target.value)}
        />

        <Output
          title="Output Two"
          value={0.0775 * Math.pow(outputOneVariable, 0.46)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just save the output of the Math calculation to the state as well and then only update it when variableOne or variableTwo change with useEffect.

```js
  const [outputOneCalc, setOutputOneCalc] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOutputOneCalc(Math.pow(
      0.01 * variableTwo * (460 + 26 * variableOne),
      1.5
    ));
  }, [variableOne, variableTwo]);
```

Then you can remove the calculation from the click handler and the JSX:

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
    setOutputOneVariable(outputOneCalc);
    setLink(!link);
};
```

JSX:

```
<Output
          title="Output One"
          value={outputOneCalc}
        />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-mendeleev-1tbqp?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

Mike's answer is the preferred & better answer.

(You could still read my answer as it provides another solution + you could learn from it aswell)

### Original Answer:

#### It's quite easy (:

You can move the calculation logic into  a separate function,  
which will be at the componenet-scope level.  
Let's call it **calculateOutputOneVariable()**.  
(Although I suggest you do some work on renamings,  
because *"Output One"* & *"Output Two"* doesn't mean anything, to me at least).

In that separate function, you'll implement the calculation logic like so:

```
const calculateOutputOneVariable = () => (
    Math.pow(0.01 * variableTwo * (460 + 26 * variableOne), 1.5)
);
```

Then you could just use it inside clickHandler() and as the Output *value* attribute:

```
const clickHandler = () => {
    setOutputOneVariable(calculateOutputOneVariable());
    setLink(!link);
};

...

return (
    ...
        ...
        <Output
            title="Output One"
            value={calculateOutputOneVariable()}
        />
        ...
    ...
);
```

#### *Pro Tip:*

Move the second inline calculation to a separate function as well (Even tho it's only written once).  
It will be clearer and more readable if you name some logic rather then just throwing it as it is .

So, from:

```
<Output
  title="Output Two"
  value={0.0775 * Math.pow(outputOneVariable, 0.46)}
/>
```

It'll become:

```
<Output
  title="Output Two"
  value={calculateAnotherValue()} // You should ofcourse name it differently
/>
```